# Haddock: imported class instances are not documented

Tags: haskell, instance, typeclass, haddock

Due to mutually dependent imports I had to move the class instances in an `Instances` module and my datatypes in a `Types` module. The definitions of both two modules are then re-exported by the main module of the package.

Haddock lists for my type the class instances derived with `deriving` but all the others are missing (though they seem correctly exported and working). Is it normal or should they be listed as well? What can I do?

[This](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/number) is the package if needed.

Thank you.